# how to perform the action sendbackward and sendfront in Android

Tags: android

```
I need a suggestion that how to perform the sendbackward and sendfront action in Android.

Actually Im having 2 images in my mapview and the second image is overlapped with the first one half of it.Here I need a suggestion when I click on to the first image it should come front and the secod image should go front and its vice versa.

Hope I will get a quick response from ur side.
```

Thanks all,
monish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I know the root cause for giving vote as -1 for this post.

use this method :

mapview.bringToFront()